# Trigger a function for when checkbox is checked/unchecke?

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox

i need to recalculate a total price for each change on the page. Select menus and checkboxes. For select menus i use

```
  $('select').on('change', function() {
        calculatePrice();
    });
```

but now i need something similar for

```
  $('input checkbox').on('change', function() {
        calculatePrice();
    });
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Are you not able to target the element? Or are you not seeing the event fired?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    calculatePrice();
});
```

Comment: There is a build-in selector to match checkbox types: `input:checkbox`.

Comment: @Lix of course. There are many different ways to do the same. So this is just one possible way

Comment: You are correct. However, of the possible ways, this method simply contains extra (unneeded) characters which harms the readability of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exact same logic (even the same function) for this:

```
$('select, input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  calculatePrice();
});
```

What I've done here is setup a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for the same callback: `'select, input:checkbox'`. This selector will target **any** `<select>` and also **any** `<input type="checkbox" />` elements. When either triggers a change event, the `calculatePrice()` function will be called.

I would also recommend that you give some identification properties to your elements, for example a class value such as `triggers_calculate`. Then your selector will have improved readability and would look something like this:

```
$('.triggers_calculate')
```

The selector will match only elements with the `triggers_calculate` class and when they fire the `change` event the function will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Separate selectors with a comma:

```
$('select, :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    calculatePrice();
});
```

or simply use `$(':input')` which would also include text inputs, textareas, radio buttons. Don't know if you need them though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="contextmenu">
    <form>
        <table border width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>Student</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="stu" id="Student">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>House Type</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="accom" value="100" id="a1">
                    <label for="a1">Hotel</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="accom" value="0" id="a2">
                    <label for="a2">House</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        $('select, input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
            calculatePrice();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```